# Parse trail period and data store limitation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am developing an app in iOS and using backend as a parse, but i want to know the limitation of data in parse.com for a free trial and also time period of it.
For example how many table I can create for free trial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the limitations of the parse.

**1.Go to parse.com**

**2.Select Pricing menu**

That page give you all details which limitations are there in free version.

This is reference link:
https://parse.com/pricing

Comment: I had referred that link but not getting any period time or space limitation of data. If you know please tell me.

Comment: You can store upto 20Gb database store

Comment: 30 requests in 1 second, If the request exceed above 30 in 1 sec then parse give the error when request to fetch data

Comment: I can use account till I am not using space 20 GB ?

Comment: Yes you can use upto 20GB, If your app is not like bug app and not so images based app this will be enough for you.

Comment: Is there any time duration limit like you can use parse account for time period of 30 days ?

Comment: How to show stored table occupied space in parse.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97962/discussion-between-jaimish-and-florence).

Comment: there is no limitation of using free version of parse and if you want to check your used storage you can find in Analytics module of Parse in your created app